# Magento - Get attribute options value and quantity

Tags: magento, custom-attributes

Hello and good day to all the members of this great community. I'm still new in PHP and especially in Magento.

I'm not posting, waiting for answers, and leaving without replying back. This is a learning process. I hope to get a great support from all of you.

I have a product. I did create custom option for the product, that is an attribute named "a_size". The attribute has value of S, M and L. Each of the value has quantity.

In the single product view, I would like to call all the available size. That is the size (S, M, or L) that has quantity more than 0. I just want to show the available size, not how much the size left.

Can anybody guide me? I'm using Magento 1.7.x and as far for this 2 weeks, I did try pretty many of suggested answers from the community thru the search function.

The replies will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: hi, please refer https://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

Comment: Hi, thank you, Jaydeep Pandya. That link teach how to insert the option for the product. What am I looking for is the way to call the value to the frontend.

Comment: call the value to the frontend means product's attribute value?

Comment: Yes. The value for the custom attribute. Did try many ways, either I did it wrong or I missed some code. Can you suggest me?

Comment: If you get the product Id then you can try with below code :
**$product** is your productId => $_product = $product; 
echo $_product->getCustomOptionName(); 
getCustomOptionName e.g for auction_type -> getAuction_type();

Comment: Sadly it returns blank. Below is my code:

`<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>`

And I want to get the available size to put it after **'In Stock'**

Comment: If you are getting product Id in **$product** then the below code will surely work. And for Quantity you **$_product = $product; 
echo $_product->getQty();**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think the `getQty` will only return the total quantity of the products. What am I trying to do here is to call the **available size**.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to try.

Firstly check that when you set up your new attribute in the Magento Admin (Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attribute) that in the `Frontend Properties` box you have set `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` to `yes`.

To get size values I use this code:

```
$cabac_sizeAttribute = $_product->getAttributeText("a_size");
```

but I have other code for getting attribute values that goes like this:

```
$_product_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
$temp = $_product_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getASize(), 'a_size');
```

I think it is related to the type of attribute: text, dropdown, multiselect etc so try both and see how you get on. But really the function `productAttribute()` is just applying formatting. You can read the function in the file `app/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Output.php`

Also, I wonder, if you have set up a *configurable product* and you are on the product view page then you will be viewing the *configurable product*. **That product won't have an `a_size` value**: you are trying to access the `a_size` attribute of the simple products that make up the configurable product, yes? Everything I wrote above is (I think) correct but to get the attribute of the simple products that are part of a configured product you should study the code in the function `getJsonConfig()` of the `file app/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php`

And in particular to these lines:

```
//file: file app/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php 
//class: Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
//function: getJsonConfig()

foreach ($this->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
    $productId  = $product->getId();

    foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
        $productAttribute   = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
        $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
        $attributeValue     = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());
```

Being careful about variable naming: `$product` is local here, I suggest changing it, and about `$this` - but if you are in a `.phtml` of the product view for configurables then I think your `$this` is already `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable`

Welcome to Magento coding. You are doing well; it is a long but rewarding path. (hints: `local.xml` is your vital friend and so is [Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) if you haven't come across his content yet.)

[Additionally, (*welcome to Magento*) I think you are trying to say eg S and L are out of stock and M is in stock but actually the function getAllowProducts() will disallow a product with zero stock and exclude it from the returned object. You will need to use

$allProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getUsedProducts(null, $this->getProduct());

(taken from function `getAllowProducts()` in file `app/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php`)

and then, if needed, check that each product is allowed to be shown eg status=ENABLED, and then check its stock level...
]

Malachy.

Comment: Wow. Seems like I have to study more. Thank you for the reply, Malachy. Appreciate it. Will try to understand those first and will get to you soon. I WILL.

Comment: You were right. They are simple products, not configurable. Now I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: What point are you stuck at? Do not be downhearted; there is always a way.

Are you stuck because the single product page is displaying a simple product? You can find out what the configured product is by calling `$cabac_productParentId = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($cabac_productId);`

In the store I worked on I knew only one parent ID would be returned but the general case is that more than one configured product ID could be returned.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to echo this code and it returned blank. Actually, I don't know where to put this code on. So I echoed it.

I'm working on product\view\type\default.phtml as i aware the single product page of mine is calling the data from the phtml file. Did I do right?

I think I'm lost inside this rarely known coding. I'm sorry if I took your time pretty much.

Comment: Hi Maya, Can we step back a bit? I'm confused. Are we talking about a configured product or a simple product. Also I recommend you make sure that each of the S M and L sizes are all in stock and are all visible - it will help you and later you can code the zero-stock situation which can be harder depending on your store settigns. Did this code `$cabac_sizeAttribute = $_product->getAttributeText("a_size");` return anything?

Comment: Thank you, Malachy. Let me clear it again. The products are simple products. My current template already has the dropdown menu for "a_size" in the option. What am I trying to do is - I want to make labels for the products. The label will show either image or text (e.g. available in size S M L). As I understood, you said the products must be in configurable products to call those sizes, not simple products. Am I right? The sizes are visible. The code above return blank.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still confused. Do you mean the S M and L sizes are all for one SKU? So you have one simple product but it can be sold as S M or L?

Comment: Yes. There are 3 different sizes for one product.

Comment: Hmmm, no, well, I hope you don't mind me saying that that is a little unusual. Has your client defined it this way? It would be more traditional to have three unique SKUs (you know it means 'stock keeping unit') one for S, one for M and one for L and enter these as three different simple products. Then create a fourth product - this time a configured product - give it a fourth unique SKU and configure it to be made up of the three simple products S, M and L.

Comment: This way Magento will be able to track the stock levels of each simple product. That is my recommendation. You should discuss it with your client and maybe you could re-read the [Magento User's Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/user-guide-download) about the different product types. I think you will find it exceptionally difficult to have one simple product for S, M and L.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values of your drop down attribute use the following code

```
$_product->getASize();
```

and initially load the product object

Comment: Thank you @teja_korlapati but it results nothing. Will this code really return the available size of attribute named "a_size"? I mean like **'In Stock S M L'**

Comment: your attribute, is it a drop down?

Comment: Thank you. But still not working. Yes, my attribute is a drop down.